# How to create an activity for both ZIP and Unzip input

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-designautomation

I am trying to run a Revit plugin on Forge Design Automation, the input to the plugin are Revit files from BIM 360 that are accessed using BIM 360 APIs. If the Revit document has links, it's downloaded as a zip file (containing the links), otherwise, it's a single Revit file. How can I define my activity so it can handle both scenarios? More specifically, how should I set:

data['parameters']['rvtFile']['zip']

In my activity?

I don't know if the file is downloaded as a ZIP file or not before it's downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know if the file is downloaded as a ZIP file or not before it's downloaded.

To determine if your Revit file downloaded from BIM 360 is a zip file, you can use this [BIM 360 API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-GET/). If the response has `isCompositeDesign = true`, it will download as a zip file with `eTransmit` package. If not, it will download as a Revit file. To understand why your file may sometimes be downloaded as a zip package see [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/bim-360/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Why-a-RVT-model-is-sometimes-downloaded-as-ZIP-from-BIM-360.html).

For usage of a zip package as input file in Design Automation, you can follow the instructions for `pathInZip` in our documentation and/or see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65947651/11057988).

**Edit (5/24):**

Also see a new [blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/make-composite-revit-design-work-design-automation-api-revit) post on the topic. Refer to the usage of `arguments.inputFile.zip` and `arguments.inputFile.pathInZip` in the workitem. This way you can use the same activity and include these argument values when the posting the workitem when your input file is a composite design.

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thanks for the response. Do I need to use two separate activities if the file is zipped and if it't not? Or can the same activity be used for both cases?

Comment: Eason created a [blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/make-composite-revit-design-work-design-automation-api-revit) here about this yesterday. I suspect you should be able to use the same activity. Just need to use the switches at the time you post workitem. I updated my answer with the edits.

Comment: Thanks Rahul and Eason, this is very helpful! In the blog post there was no reference on whether the same activity can be used for both zipped and unzipped inputs. Looking at Design Automation documentations on publishing an activity:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step5-publish-activity/
It seems like this needs to be defined in advance. But maybe I can leave out parameters.rvtFile.zip from my activity definition?

Comment: That is correct. Any activity parameter that can be overridden in workitem argument, can also be left out in the activity definition.